# How do I get to the beginning or end of the array properly? How do I pass in a reference of currently selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Thanks for taking time to help out. CoffeeScript version is 1.3.3; jQuery version is from Rails 3.2.8 jquery-rails gem 2.1.3.

I have an array of poems with their respective links stored in $poems_for_year_hrefs. I am able to grab the index of the elements in $poems_for_year_hrefs using $.each() and storing in poemUrls.

The page's next link, when clicked on, is used to increment  the index of poemUrls to the next element  and update the $next_link's href attribute. If the index exceeds the length of the poemUrls, then the index is set back to 0 to give the first element in the array.

The page's previous link, when clicked on, is used to obtain the next element in the $poems_for_year_hrefs by decrementing the current index in poemUrl by 1.  Then it updates the $prev_link's href attribute. If the current index is less than or equal to 0 it goes to the last element in the poemUrls array.

Here is the CoffeeScript code:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $poem_years = $('#poems-for-year ul li a')
    $poem = $('#main-poem').hide()
    $poem_years.click -> 
      $poem.eq(0).fadeIn('slow', -> 
        $poem.slideDown('slow')
     )
     console.log "Clicked on a poem title with index of #{$poem_years.index(@)}"

    $poems_for_year_hrefs = $('#poems-for-year ul li a[href]')

    index = $poems_for_year_hrefs.index(@)
    poemUrls = []
    $($poems_for_year_hrefs).each((i)->
      poemUrls[i] = $(@).attr('href')
      poemUrls.join(",")
    )
    console.log "The poemUrls array contains: #{poemUrls}"

    $next_link = $('#previous-next li a').last()
    $next_link.click ->
      if index >= poemUrls.length
        index = 0
        $next_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
      else
        index += 1
        console.log "$next_link was clicked on!"
        $next_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
        console.log "$next_link href was set to #{$next_link.attr('href')}"

    $prev_link = $('#previous-next li a').first()
    $prev_link.click ->
      if index <= 0
        index = poemUrls.length
        $prev_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
      else
        index -= 1
        console.log "$prev_link was clicked on!"
        $prev_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
      console.log "$prev_link href was set to #{$prev_link.attr('href')}"
```

and the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/poetry.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="XcXpd5Fg50gvWP8tVLB0/HOfBxoPaTOJ9q37zArrrFo=" name="csrf-token" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <div id="content">
    <h1>poetry</h1>
    <section id="poem-selections">
    <article id="archives">
    <nav id="archive-year-nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/poetry/2011">2011</a>
    <li><a href="/poetry/2012">2012</a>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="poems-for-year">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/poetry/2012/1st%20poem%20title?id=16" data-remote="true">1st poem   title</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/poetry/2012/2nd%20poem%20title?id=17" data-remote="true">2nd poem  title</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/poetry/2012/3rd%20poem%20title?id=18" data-remote="true">3rd poem   title</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

   </div>
   </article>

   </section>

   <section id="main">

   <article>
   <div id="main-poem">
   <h3>2nd poem title</h3>
   <p>2nd poem verse</p>
   </div>
   <nav>
   <ul id="previous-next">
   <li><a href="/poetry/2012/previous_poem/2nd%20poem%20title?id=17" data-  remote="true">previous</a></li>
   <li><a href="/poetry/2012/next_poem/2nd%20poem%20title?id=17" data-remote="true">next</a>      </li>
   </ul>
   </nav>

   </article>

   </section>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am using Ajax to make updates to the main-poem div. If I click on the 2nd poem (id=17) in poems-for-year div, the main-poem div will update, showing the contents of the 2nd poem (id=17). If I click on the next link, the first poem that's indexed in the poemUrls at position 0 is returned. Then I click next and the poem in position 1 of the poemUrls is returned and then next again and the position 2 is returned moves along like it should. Once I reach the end of the array, I click the next link to cycle the index count back to 0 to reach the beginning of the poemUrls array, I need to click next twice. The first click does nothing.

The same issue is experienced, if I select the 3rd poem, then click the previous link. The index starts at 0 and then returns the 1st position of the poemUrl array. Click previous, goes through array decrementing the index by one. Gets to the 1st element, then I need to click previous twice to get to the last position in the array.

***Why do I need to click it twice? Is it a variable that loses context?***

***Also how can I pass the reference of the currently selected element to $next_link.click  so it knows what the current element selected is and can get the proper next element rather than starting at 0? In other words, if I click on the 2nd poem (id=17) in poems-for-year, how can I get $next_link.click to return the 3rd poem (id=18), or if I click previous get $prev_link.click to return the 1st poem (id=16)?***

The CoffeeScript compiled to JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $next_link, $poem, $poem_years, $poems_for_year_hrefs, $prev_link, index, poemUrls;
  $poem_years = $('#poems-for-year ul li a');
  $poem = $('#main-poem').hide();
  $poem_years.click(function() {
    $poem.eq(0).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      return $poem.slideDown('slow');
    });
    return console.log("Clicked on a poem title with index of " + ($poem_years.index(this)));
  });
  $poems_for_year_hrefs = $('#poems-for-year ul li a[href]');
  index = $poems_for_year_hrefs.index(this);
  poemUrls = [];
  $($poems_for_year_hrefs).each(function(i) {
    poemUrls[i] = $(this).attr('href');
    return poemUrls.join(",");
  });
  console.log("The poemUrls array contains: " + poemUrls);
  $next_link = $('#previous-next li a').last();
  $next_link.click(function() {
    if (index >= poemUrls.length) {
      index = 0;
      return $next_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href');
    } else {
      index += 1;
      console.log("$next_link was clicked on!");
      $next_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href');
      return console.log("$next_link href was set to " + ($next_link.attr('href')));
    }
  });
  $prev_link = $('#previous-next li a').first();
  return $prev_link.click(function() {
    if (index <= 0) {
      index = poemUrls.length;
      $prev_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href');
    } else {
      index -= 1;
      console.log("$prev_link was clicked on!");
      $prev_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href');
    }
    return console.log("$prev_link href was set to " + ($prev_link.attr('href')));
  });
});
```

**Edit**

```
    $next_link = $('#previous-next li a').last()
    $next_link.click ->
      nextPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index >= poemUrls.length - 1 then 0 else index + 1 ]
      console.log "When I call $next_link_click, nextPoemUrl is: #{nextPoemUrl}"
      $next_link.attr('href', nextPoemUrl).attr('href')
      console.log "When I call $next_link_click, next_link href is: #{$next_link.href}"

    $prev_link = $('#previous-next li a').first()
    $prev_link.click ->
      prevPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index <= poemUrls.length - 1 then 0 else index - 1 ]
      console.log "When I call $prev_link.click, prevPoemUrl is #{prevPoemUrl}"
      $prev_link.attr('href', prevPoemUrl).attr('href')
      console.log "When I call $prev_link_click, prev_link href is #{$prev_link.href}"
```

**Testing results:**
The poemUrls array contains these: /poetry/2011/1st%20poem%20title%202011?id=19,/poetry/2011/2nd%20poem%20title%202011?id=20,/poetry/2011/3rd%20poem%20title%202011?id=21

Clicked on a poem title with index of 2 (last poem in array containing 3 poems)
When I call $prev_link.click, prevPoemUrl is /poetry/2011/3rd%20poem%20title%202011?id=21 (last poem in array)
When I call $prev_link_click, prev_link href is undefined

I click on the last poem again:
Clicked on a poem title with index of 2 (last poem)

When I call $next_link_click, nextPoemUrl is: /poetry/2011/1st%20poem%20title%202011?id=19

When I call $next_link_click, next_link href is: undefined

Seems that the prev returns the last poem indexed and next returns the first poem indexed
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source for getting the current position of the clicked poem, and having the next and previous link proceed accordingly. It's a rough draft, but works:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $poem_years = $('#poems-for-year ul li a')
    $poem = $('#main-poem').hide()
    $poem_years.click -> 
      $poem.eq(0).fadeIn('slow', -> 
        $poem.slideDown('slow')
      )
      console.log "Clicked on a poem title with index of #{$poem_years.index(@)}" # <-- where gets current index of clicked poem title!
      $poems_for_year_hrefs = $('#poems-for-year ul li a[href]')
      index = $poem_years.index(@) # <-- Assign the current reference to the index variable
      poemUrls = []
      $($poems_for_year_hrefs).each((i)->
        poemUrls[i] = $(@).attr('href')
        poemUrls.join(",")
      )

      console.log "The poemUrls array contains these: #{poemUrls}"

      $prev_link = $('#previous-next li a').first()
      $prev_link.click ->
       console.log "the prevPoemUrl is: #{poemUrls[index]}"
       if index <= 0
         index = poemUrls.length - 1
         $prev_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
         $('#main-poem').hide().fadeIn('slow')
         console.log "$prev_link href when <= poemUrls.length was set to #{$prev_link.attr('href')}"
         console.log "The poemUrls when <= poemUrls.length is: #{poemUrls[index]}"
       else
         index -= 1
         console.log "$prev_link was clicked on!"
         $prev_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
         $('#main-poem').hide().fadeIn('slow')
         console.log "$prev_link href was set to #{$prev_link.attr('href')}"   
         console.log "The poemUrls poemUrls.length is: #{poemUrls[index]}"

      $next_link = $('#previous-next li a').last()
      $next_link.click ->
        if index >= poemUrls.length - 1
          index = 0
          $next_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
          $('#main-poem').hide().fadeIn('slow')
          console.log "$next_link href when >= poemUrls.length was set to #{$next_link.attr('href')}"
          console.log "The poemUrl when >= poemUrls.length is: #{poemUrls[index]}"
        else
          index += 1
          console.log "$next_link was clicked on!"
          $next_link.attr('href', poemUrls[index]).attr('href')
          console.log "$next_link href was set to #{$next_link.attr('href')}"
          console.log "The poemUrls when < poemUrls.length is: #{poemUrls[index]}"
          $('#main-poem').hide().fadeIn('slow')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). The errors are at,

```
if index >= poemUrls.length
    index = 0
...
if index <= 0
    index = poemUrls.length
```

In your example, `poemUrls.length` is **3**, and since JavaScript arrays are zero-based (they start counting at zero) the valid indexes are **0, 1, and 2**. The first snippet will let the index get to **3** before setting it to **0**. The second snippet will set the index to **3** when it reaches **0**. The corrected code is,

```
if index >= poemUrls.length - 1
    index = 0
...
if index <= 0
    index = poemUrls.length - 1
```

**Edit**

Addressing the second question, if you want to access the siblings of the current poem, you can use your array and index structure. The quick CoffeeScript solution would be,

```
prevPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index <= 0 then poemUrls.length - 1 else index - 1 ]
nextPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index >= poemUrls.length - 1 then 0 else index + 1 ]
```

Comment: Thanks atonparker! That definitely fixed the 'clicking twice at the end of the array' issue and I checked your answer as acceptable.

Comment: Any advice on the 2nd part of this issue:  How can I pass the reference of the currently selected element to **$next_link.click** so it knows what the current element selected is and can get the proper next element rather than starting at 0? In other words, if I click on the 2nd poem (id=17) in **poems-for-year**, how can I get **$next_link.click** to return the 3rd poem (id=18), or if I click on the previous link, get **$prev_link.click** to return the 1st poem (id=16)?

Comment: Since all the conditional logic is in between the [] to find the index, would it be implemented like this?

   `$next_link = $('#previous-next li a').last()`


   `$next_link.click ->'

    `nextPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index >= poemUrls.length - 1 then 0 else index + 1 ]'

    `$next_link.attr('href', nextPoemUrl).attr('href')`


    `$prev_link = $('#previous-next li a').first()`

    `$prev_link.click ->'

      `prevPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index <= 0 then poemUrls.length - 1 else index - 1 ]`

      `$prev_link.attr('href', prevPoemUrl).attr('href')`

Comment: The comment stripped your formatting, but it looks fine to me. Could you try it out and edit your question if it doesn't work like you expect?

Comment: @antonparker, please check the last edit for latest. Thanks for helping get this far man. Couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: The `prevPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index <= 0 then poemUrls.length - 1 else index - 1 ]` and `nextPoemUrl = poemUrls[ if index >= poemUrls.length - 1 then 0 else index + 1 ]` isn't getting the index. It returns **-1** on both.

Is there some what of passing `this` or `@` so poemUrls know where its correct position should be?